# Javascript callback within class loses binding

Tags: javascript, callback, mootools

I have a problem with my class where I set a callback function to fire after an ajax request, this works fine except for the callback then having this= window instead of this = the calling class. I have tried fiddling with the bindings etc to no avail. any help appreciated.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id'])){
    echo json_encode(array('key' => 'val'));
    die;
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/linkup/js/mootools-core-1.4.3-full-compat-yc.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/linkup/js/mootools-more-1.4.0.1.js" charset="utf-8"></script><script>
var myClass = new Class({
    blah: function(){
        console.log('this worked ok');
    },
    foo: function(){
        this.blah(); // at this point it is failing with "unknown function"
    },
    bar: function(){
        this.reqJSON({id:1,req:'grabpoints'},this.foo);
    },
    // data - an aray containing some data to post {id:1,req:'grabpoints'}
    // onS - a function to fire on return of data
    reqJSON: function(data,onS){
        if (this.jsonRequest) this.jsonRequest.cancel();
        this.jsonRequest = new Request.JSON({
                url: 'test.php',
                onRequest: function (object){
                    console.log('sending json');
                },
                onSuccess: function (object){
                    console.log('json success');
                    onS(object);
                }
            }
        ).post(data);
    },

});
var o = new myClass();
o.bar();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is never part of an inherited scope (i.e. the closure) for a function, but instead determined when the function is called, in this case by `onS(object)`. Called this way, the function is just that - a function. You need to call `this.onS(object)`, but this won't work in your case because the `onSuccess` function does not know about `this` either.

To call the foo/onS function with the outermost object as `this` you must save a reference to it in another variable, commonly called `that`:

```
reqJSON: function(data,onS){
    var that = this;
    ...

    onSuccess: function (object){
        console.log('json success');
        that.onS(object);
    }
```

Comment: what if the binding is to be on an object / class instance that is not in your myClass instance? you are creating an implicit bond between the two when there doesn't need to be one. they should do the binding of the function before passing it on. in any case, you should do `onS.apply(that, arguments)` as there is more to the response

Comment: @DimitarChristoff - thanks so much for this, thought i was just being daft, but I would never have thought of this approach. It has solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

change this

```
bar: function(){
    this.reqJSON({id:1,req:'grabpoints'},this.foo);
}
```

to :

```
bar: function(){
  var self = this;
  this.reqJSON({id:1,req:'grabpoints'},self.foo);
}
```

Comment: you are not doing the binding this way, this is a reference too far upstream.